# Kaa - Your First Application Tutorial - Where is the Application Directory?

Tags: c++, kaa

I am following this [tutorial](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/).

At the Preparation step, under C++ it says:

> 3. In the application directory, create a CMakeLists.txt file with the following contents:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
 project(Cpp-SDK-your-first-Kaa-application CXX)

 add_subdirectory(kaa)
 add_executable(kaa-app main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(kaa-app kaacpp)
```

Where is the Application Directory?

I have tried putting it in the main directory (which overwrites the CMakeLists.txt file that is already there, and that doesn't work. (It gives error messages)

I have tried putting it in the kaa directory, which works, but it does not create the kaa-app executable as it should.

So I don't understand what it means by Application Directory, or even if that is the issue at all.

Also, does main.cpp go in the same place or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application directory is root directory of your application (all files, directories should be placed there).
Here is example of directory structure:
`-my_application_folder/` this is an Application directory.
`|--main.cpp` source code of your application.
`|--kaa/` directory with kaa SDK.
`|--CMakeLists.txt` build file that should be placed in directory `my_application_folder/`(with content you showed in question).
`|--build/` folder where `cmake` should be executed.

Comment: When I do that, it give the error message: /my_application_folder/kaa does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file. If I put the same CMakeLists.txt file in the kaa  directory it still does not work.

Comment: You must execute `cmake` from build directory

Comment: I am executing `cmake` from the build directory. Look at my updated post above.